# counting cells in excel / Access query with particular value

Tags: excel

I have excel sheet containing present, absent, and holidays. Want to calculate/count Absents(a) but it should include holidays (h) where absent is on both sides of holidays (i.e preceding and succeeding) or in Ms-Access query.

### | 1 | 2 |3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10

| P | P | A | P | A | A | H | H | A | A

ANSWER REQUIRED TOTAL ABSENTS : 07 (3,5,6,7,8,9,10)

Answer (score 1):

This formula uses multiple If conditions: If =A OR If (=H AND previous=A AND next=A)

=COUNTIF(B1:I1; "=A") + COUNTIFS(B1:I1; "=H"; OFFSET(B1:I1; 0; -1); "=A"; OFFSET(B1:I1; 0; 1);  "=A") + COUNTIFS(I1:B1; "=H"; OFFSET(B1:I1; 0; -1); "=A"; OFFSET(B1:I1; 0; 1); "=H"; OFFSET(B1:I1; 0; 2); "=A")

Insert your range, but note I used B1 instead of A1 for the example because otherwise offset throws an error.

Edit: The modification I made (the third CountIFs) will work for 2 consecutive H's, but for more than that you would need to create another CountIFS to iterate through further OR conditions. Maybe someone else has a cleaner solution?